# How to access an actor from within a filter closure

Tags: swift, concurrency, swift-concurrency

I'm having trouble working out how to access an actor from a filter closure. Take this example code:

```swift
import Foundation

actor MyActor {
    var contents: [String]
    
    init() {
        self.contents = []
    }
}


let myActor = MyActor()
let list: [String] = []

Task {
    list.filter { item in myActor.contents.contains { $0 == item } }
}
```

I get the syntax error: `Actor-isolated property 'contents' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context`. Which makes sense, but I just cannot work out how to provide the correct syntax.

Comment: What would it even mean though, suppose for example the actor's contents mutate while you are filtering your list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the actor's contents in a local `let` constant first, then use that local constant in `filter`:

```
Task {
    let actorContents = await myActor.contents
    let result = list.filter { item in actorContents.contains { $0 == item } }
}
```

You wouldn't want `filter` to use the updated `myActor.contents` halfway through, if `myActor.contents` changes at some point during the filtering, right? Therefore, make a local copy of it first, and use that.

Also, consider using a `Set` for better efficiency:

```
let actorContents = Set(await myActor.contents)
let result = list.filter { item in actorContents.contains(item) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to move the filtering routine into the actor:

```swift
actor MyActor {
    var contents: Set<String> = []

    func filtering(_ items: [String]) -> [String] {
        items.filter { contents.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Then, that simplifies the call point:

```swift
func foo() {
    Task {
        let filtered = await myActor.filtering(list)
    }
}
```

This moves the synchronization logic to the actor (where it belongs, IMHO).

Comment: in this example I agree. In a more general pattern, say where the actor is protecting a dictionary, the other method applies also.